# How to inherit same class multiple times?

Tags: c++, inheritance

Is it possible to inherit kind of two same classes like this? I was able to compile this on msvc, but failed to compile on g++/clang++. I'm getting error:

```
Source.cpp:14:12: warning: direct base 'a' is inaccessible due to ambiguity:
    struct b -> struct a
    struct b -> class_combiner<struct a> -> struct a [-Winaccessible-base]
struct b : public a, public class_combiner<a> {
           ^~~~~~~~
Source.cpp:17:12: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'b' to base class 'a':
    struct b -> struct a
    struct b -> class_combiner<struct a> -> struct a
        a::f();
```

Source:

```
template <typename T>
struct class_combiner : public T {

    using T::T;

};

struct a {

    void f() {}

};

struct b : public a, public class_combiner<a> {

    void f2() {
        a::f();
        b::class_combiner::f();
    }

};


int main() {
    b x;
    x.f2();
}
```

Comment: If you do it this way, you have two instances of `a` in `b`. For this "diamond inheritance" pattern, consider using virtual inheritance instead (then there will be only a single instance of `a`).

Comment: I ran into this very same problem, and spoke with Bjarne Stroustrup on the phone.  He recommended making a helper struct just to aid as a discriminator, `struct a_helper : a {};`.  And inherit from that `struct b : public a_helper, public class_combiner<a> {` so you can `a_helper::a::f();`, otherwise there is an ambiguity.  Assuming you don't want the `a` base objects to be the identically same `a` base object.

Comment: Thanks @Eljay That seemed to do the trick. I'll post the answer in case someone will ever come against this same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Doable quick fix I came up with:

```
template <typename T, unsigned int instance>
struct class_combiner : public T {

    using T::T;

};

struct a {

    void f() {}

};

struct b : public class_combiner<a, 0>, public class_combiner<a, 1> {

    void f2() {
        class_combiner<a, 0>::f();
        class_combiner<a, 1>::f();
    }

};


int main() {
    b x;
    x.f2();
}
```